# .net MVC 2 default Route suddenly stopped working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes

today the default route for my site stopped working, but the strange thing is that the global.ascx has not changed at all.

when i enter the URL mysite.com/

i get this 404 error

The resource cannot be found.
Requested URL: /Views/Start/Index.aspx

i have a bog standard default MVC route

```
        routes.MapRoute(
                    "Default",
                    "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                    new { controller = "Index", action = "Index", id = "" }
                );
```

the oddball thing is that even if i create a Start folder with a copy of my index view, it still doesn’t work and throws the same 404 error.

has anyone else had this issue ??

any help is most appreciated

Truegilly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Re-add ASP.Net MVC's default `Default.aspx` file to the site root.

This file forces requests to `/` to run through the routing engine.

Comment: thanks for the sugesstion but it still doesnt work, ive created a default.aspx in the shared and default index view folder, and still same error, i have copied the view folder from my server where it works onto my local machine where it doesnt and still no joy, even if i delete the view folder i get the same 404 looking for -> Requested URL: /Views/Start/Index.aspx

Comment: this is even stranger, on my new server, i still have the same problem, yet this time it says it cannot find Requested URL: /Root.aspx - any ideas ??

Answer (score 1):

Although not necessarily the answer to this question, when Haack's debugger is showing that your routing tables are set up fine but you're still getting 404s, check your Controller is public!